# Failed to send data to kafka

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to run flink locally with 8 task slots for a job with parallelism 8. I am using FlinkKafkaProducer011 as the sink. The job runs fine for about 20 mins and checkpointing succeeds during that period. However the job fails after that and I get the following error:

> org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafka011Exception:
>   Failed to send data to Kafka: The server disconnected before a
>   response was received.

I've tried increasing the request.timeout.ms to 15 minutes, but still no luck.

Answer (score -1):

try this example it worked for me, https://github.com/kali786516/FlinkStreamAndSql/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/aws/examples/kafka/consumer/KafkaConsumer.scala

```
package com.aws.examples.kafka.consumer

import java.util.{Properties, UUID}

import org.apache.flink.api.common.restartstrategy.RestartStrategies
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.{TableEnvironment, Types}
import org.apache.flink.table.descriptors.{Json, Kafka, Rowtime, Schema}
import org.apache.flink.types.Row
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat.JDBCInputFormatBuilder
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCOutputFormat
import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.CsvTableSink

object KafkaConsumer {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var params: ParameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

    /*
    if (params.getNumberOfParameters < 4) {
      System.out.println("\nUsage: ReadWriteKafkaTableSQLAPI --read-topic <topic> --write-topic <topic> --bootstrap.servers <kafka brokers> --group.id <groupid>")
      return
    }
    */

    val kparams: Properties = params.getProperties
    kparams.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
    kparams.setProperty("flink.starting-position", "earliest")
    kparams.setProperty("group.id", UUID.randomUUID.toString)
    kparams.setProperty("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")


    // setup streaming environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.getConfig.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(4, 10000))
    env.enableCheckpointing(300000) // 300 seconds

    env.getConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(params)
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    env.setParallelism(1)

    val tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)

    tableEnv.connect(new Kafka().version("0.11").topic("creditcardTransaction").
      property("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092"))
      .withSchema(new Schema()
        .field("cc_num", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("first_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("last_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("trans_num", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("trans_time", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("category_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("merchant_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("amt_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("merch_lat", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("merch_long", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("ts", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP)
        .rowtime(new Rowtime().timestampsFromSource.watermarksPeriodicBounded(1000)))
        .withFormat(new Json().deriveSchema).inAppendMode.registerTableSource("creditcardTransactiontable")

    val query = "SELECT distinct cc_num,first_column,last_column,trans_num,trans_time,category_column,merchant_column,amt_column,merch_lat,merch_long from creditcardTransactiontable where cc_num not in ('cc_num')"
    val table = tableEnv.sqlQuery(query)

    table.printSchema()

    //tEnv.toAppendStream(table, classOf[Row]).print
    tableEnv.toRetractStream(table, classOf[org.apache.flink.types.Row]).print


    /* write to kafka */

    val test = tableEnv.connect(new Kafka().version("0.11").topic("creditcardTransactionTargetTopic").
      property("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").sinkPartitionerRoundRobin).
      withSchema(new Schema()
        .field("cc_num", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("first_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("last_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("trans_num", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("trans_time", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("category_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("merchant_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("amt_column", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("merch_lat", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING)
        .field("merch_long", org.apache.flink.table.api.Types.STRING))
      .withFormat(new Json().deriveSchema).inAppendMode.registerTableSink("sinkTopic")


    val sql = "INSERT INTO sinkTopic SELECT distinct cc_num,first_column,last_column,trans_num,trans_time,category_column,merchant_column,amt_column,merch_lat,merch_long from creditcardTransactiontable where cc_num not in ('cc_num')"

    //val csvSink: CsvTableSink = new CsvTableSink("/path/to/file","~")


    tableEnv.sqlUpdate(sql)

    env.execute()


  }

}
```

POM:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>FlinkStreamAndSql</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlinkStreamAndSql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
                    <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- "package" command plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.13.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-jdbc_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--   -->
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                   <artifactId>flink-scala_2.11</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.0</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                   <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.0</version>
               </dependency>


               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                   <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.0</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                   <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis_2.11</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.0</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                   <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.0</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                   <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                   <version>2.12.8</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                   <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.8</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
                   <version>1.11.579</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                   <version>1.2.2</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                   <version>2.1</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                   <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
                   <version>1.4</version>
               </dependency>

               <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.579</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```